# poolDataSource.getConnection() hangs. Tried using ojdbc6 and ojdbc8 jars

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, connection-pooling

I am using Oracle 11g XE and java 8. I am developing  a desktop application and want to do connection pooling. The application hangs while executing `pds.getConnection();` I tried using simple JDBC, that works fine so it's not a network/DB issue.

**Here is the code I am calling:**

```
/**
 * This returns DB connection from the DB Connection Pool
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static Connection getConnection() throws IOException, SQLException {
    if (pds == null) {
        initConnectionPool();
    }
    Connection conn = pds.getConnection();
    System.out.println("Available connections after checkout: " + pds.getAvailableConnectionsCount());
    System.out.println("Borrowed connections after checkout: " + pds.getBorrowedConnectionsCount());
    return conn;
}


/**
 * init DB Connection Pool
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private static void initConnectionPool() throws IOException, SQLException {
    Properties configProperties = Utils.getConfig();

    // Get the PoolDataSource for UCP
    PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

    // Set the connection factory first before all other properties
    System.out.println("Class name :" + configProperties.getProperty("CONNECTION_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME"));
    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName(configProperties.getProperty("CONNECTION_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME"));

    System.out.println("DB URL ==" + configProperties.getProperty("DB_URL"));
    pds.setURL(configProperties.getProperty("DB_URL"));

    System.out.println("DB User ==" + configProperties.getProperty("DB_USER"));
    pds.setUser(configProperties.getProperty("DB_USER"));

    System.out.println("Password==" + configProperties.getProperty("DB_PSWD"));
    pds.setPassword(configProperties.getProperty("DB_PSWD"));

    pds.setConnectionPoolName("JDBC_UCP_POOL");

    // Default is 0. Set the initial number of connections to be created
    // when UCP is started.
    pds.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(configProperties.getProperty("INITIAL_POOL_SIZE")));

    // Default is 0. Set the minimum number of connections
    // that is maintained by UCP at runtime.
    pds.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(configProperties.getProperty("MIN_POOL_SIZE")));

    // Default is Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647). Set the maximum number of
    // connections allowed on the connection pool.
    pds.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(configProperties.getProperty("MAX_POOL_SIZE")));
}



/**
 * Loads the config file and return instance of Properties
 * 
 * @return Proterties
 * @throws IOException
 */

public static Properties getConfig() throws IOException {

    if (configProps != null)
        return configProps;
    configProps = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in;
    in = new FileInputStream("bin/resources/config.properties");
    configProps.load(in);
    in.close();
    return configProps;
}
```

**The properties used are:**

```
 DB_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE

 INITIAL_POOL_SIZE=5

 MIN_POOL_SIZE=5

 MAX_POOL_SIZE=10

 CONNECTION_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `pds` class variable. When you call `getConnection()` it is always `null`.

To make sure the method that initializes the pool is called once you can use a *static initializer block*.

```
static {
  initConnectionPool();
}
```

Comment: I have declared pds as a class level static  variable. I am calling initConnectionPool() if pds is found to be null..

Comment: I didn&#39;t ask you declared you a class variable, because it won&#39;t compile otherwise. You didn&amp;#39;t initialize that variable. The variable  should be initialized once the context is started and only once. If the variable is static you can initialize it when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. In initialize() I had declared a local variable pds. I removed that and let the class variable get initialized, the code started working. I am surprised why I did not get a NullPointerException in this case.. That could have saved a lot of time.